# windows 7 turn off sounds via cmd line or powershell

Tags: windows-7, script

Im looking for a way to write a script hat will turn off sounds.

The sounds i would like to turn off are the start navigation sound and the play windows start up sound.

is there any script that can get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this that helps a little. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/285-sounds-change.html

It doesn't tell you where everything is but if you're looking for a specific sound it works.

The way I did it was to go to Control Panel > Sounds and find the sound i want to change for example i'll choose the Asterisk Sound under the WIndows section.

So the sound name is "Windows Hardware Insert"

I then go to the registry
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps
 and right click and select "Find" then I enter the "Windows Hardware Insert" and it will show me where that registry entry is found so that I can change it.

You can then export the registry entry and edit it then write a script to apply the change by doing

```
regedit /s "Path to your registry entry"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find this sort of stuff is to export the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, usually), change the setting, export the registry again (to a different file) and run it through something like WinDiff or WinMerge to see what the differences are.

Once you know what is changed, you can use something like VBScript to automate this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell : Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Set the sound to Windows Navigation Start.wav
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.Current\", "C:\Windows\Media\Landscape\Windows Navigation Start.wav", "REG_SZ"

' Clear the sound
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.Current\", "", "REG_SZ"
```

Unfortunately not everything is as simple as this as I couldn't find anything changed in the registry that would appear to be for the Windows Start Up sound.